# for loop, some symbols exist, but some other is not

Tags: python

I met a tricky problem for a rookie.

I have some data(pettm_rank_20, roa_rank_20, roe_rank_20, npttm_rank_20 mkt_rank_20 and located_symbols):

```
pettm_rank_20   
         signal
002610.CS   -1
000002.CS   1
```

```
roa_rank_20
        signal
603719.CS   -1
000001.CS   1
```

```
roe_rank_20
        signal
300751.CS   -1
002610.CS   1
```

```
npttm_rank_20
        signal
300751.CS   -1
002610.CS   1
```

```
mkt_rank_20
        signal
000001.CS   -1
002610.CS   1
```

```
located_symbols
['000001.CS', '000002.CS', '300724.CS', '300751.CS', '002610.CS', '603719.CS']
```

the problem is in pettm_rank_20, there are only two items of located_symbols,

```
for symbol in located_symbols:
    alphaReturn = {}
    alphaReturns = 5 + (pettm_rank_20.loc[symbol]*2.5 + roa_rank_20.loc[symbol]*3 + 
                                roe_rank_20.loc[symbol]*1.1 +
                                npttm_rank_20.loc[symbol]*1.7 +
                                mkt_rank_20[symbol]*3.3)
    alphaReturn[symbol] = alphaReturns
```

The error is obvious:

```
KeyError: 'the label [000001.CS] is not in the [index]'
```

How can I solve this logic problem, sorry for my bad programming ability, I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here, some if may be needed...

From Ieo's, I created the big dic:

```
total
         signal_mkt signal_npttm signal_pettm signal_roa signal_roe
002610.CS       NaN       NaN            -1.0        NaN        NaN
000002.CS   NaN NaN 1.0  NaN                                    NaN
603719.CS   NaN NaN NaN -1.0    NaN
000001.CS   NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
300751.CS   NaN NaN NaN NaN -1.0
002610.CS   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0
300751.CS   NaN -1.0    NaN NaN NaN
002610.CS   NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
000001.CS   -1.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN
002610.CS   1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The problem is:

```
total['signal_mkt']['000001.CS']
000001.CS    NaN
000001.CS   -1.0
Name: signal_mkt, dtype: float64
```

I only need the -1 not the NaN, is there a way to solve it? I assum others may have the same problem, want to find a elegant way?

my way is a bit silly:

```
total['signal_mkt']['000001.CS'][total['signal_mkt']['000001.CS'].notna()]
000001.CS   -1.0
Name: signal_mkt, dtype: float64
```

Comment: you already know there are only sm items in the datasets posted. what do u expect to happen when you are tryign to access a key that does not exist in the dictionary ?

Comment: I just want to know the alphaReturns of every symbol in located_symbols, want to find a elegant way to achieve it

Comment: Create a dictionary of all your symbols to its values and access that instead of accessing your smaller dicts which may or maynot have keys that you are accessing.

Comment: I know this is a way, but this way has a problem, it has NaN, so I have to give a condition to choose the right one

Comment: what NaN ?? therre is no NaN in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about dictionaries in python. What you have added in your edit is not a dictionary, its a table. A dictionary is a collection of key value pairs. You give a key and say get me the value for this key.

Your array of located symbols should serve as the keys to the dictionary.

```
symbol_dict = {
        "002610.CS": -1
        "000002.CS": 1
        "603719.CS": -1
        "000001.CS": 1
        "300751.CS": -1
        "002610.CS": 1
        "300751.CS": -1
        "002610.CS": 1
        "000001.CS": -1
        "002610.CS": 1
}
```

Then when you want to access the value for a particular symbol (eg. 002610.CS), you do -`symbol_dict['002610.CS']`. This will return a key error if the key does not exist in the dictionary.

If you are not sure if a key exists in a dictionary, you can access the dictionary as this - `symbol_dict.get('non_existent_key', 'default_value')`
This will not return an error. It will return the default value if the key does not exist in the dictionary.

```
located_symbols = ['000001.CS', '000002.CS', '300724.CS', '300751.CS', '002610.CS', '603719.CS']

factor_dict = {
        "002610.CS": 2.5
        "000002.CS": 2.5
        "603719.CS": 3
        "000001.CS": 3
        "300751.CS": 1.1
        "002610.CS": 1.1
        "300751.CS": 1.7
        "002610.CS": 1.7
        "000001.CS": 3.3
        "002610.CS": 3.3
}

for each in located_symbols:
    alphaReturn = {}
    alphaReturns = 5 + symbol_dict.get(each, 0) * factor_dict.get(each, 0) # usong 0 as default
    alphaReturn[each] = alphaReturns
```

I am not sure if the calculations I have done are what you want. But the way to access a dictionary with keys that may or maynot be there is shown.

If you are using pandas(assuming since you gave a lot of tables in the question), pandas itself has a way of converting your table to a dictionary.

You can also create nested dictionaries like this -

```
symbol_dict = {
        "002610.CS": {
         "value": -1,
         "factor": 2.5
         },
        "000002.CS": {
         "value": 1,
         "factor": 2.5
        }
        "603719.CS": {
         "value": -1,
         "factor": 3
        }
        "000001.CS": {
         "value": 1,
         "factor": 3
        }
        "300751.CS": {
         "value": -1,
         "factor": 1.1
        }
        "002610.CS": {
         "value": 1,
         "factor": 1.1
        }
        "300751.CS": {
         "value": -1,
         "factor": 1.7
        }
        "002610.CS": {
         "value": 1,
         "factor": 1.7
        }
        "000001.CS": {
         "value": -1,
         "factor": 3.3
        }
        "002610.CS": {
         "value": 1,
         "factor": 3.3
        }
}
```

Your code then becomes -

```
for each in located_symbols:
    alphaReturn = {}
    if each in symbol_dict.keys():  # Check if key exists in dictionary else do nothing
      alphaReturns = 5 + symbol_dict[each]['value'] * symbol_dict[each]['factor']
      alphaReturn[each] = alphaReturns
```

Comment: I got what you mean, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

````
for symbol in located_symbols:
    try:
        a = a[symbol].loc['signal_pettm'][a[symbol].loc['signal_pettm'].notna()].values.item()
    except:
        a = 0
    try:
        b = a[symbol].loc['signal_roe'][a[symbol].loc['signal_roe'].notna()].values.item()
    except:
        b = 0
    try:
        c = a[symbol].loc['signal_roa'][a[symbol].loc['signal_roa'].notna()].values.item()
    except:
        c = 0
    try:
        d = a[symbol].loc['signal_npttm'][a[symbol].loc['signal_npttm'].notna()].values.item()
    except:
        d = 0
    try:
        e = a[symbol].loc['signal_mkt'][a[symbol].loc['signal_mkt'].notna()].values.item()
    except:
        e = 0
    
    alphaReturns = intercept+a*coe_list[0]+b*coe_list[1]+c*coe_list[2]+d*coe_list[3]+e*coe_list[4]
    alphaReturn[symbol] = (alphaReturns)```
my solution to this is too urgly, as using too many try and except, but this is only way I figured out...
````

Comment: you are using 0 if the symbol does not exist in the dictionary. Just do `get(<key>, <default>)`. Just read on how to access a dictionary.

Comment: get(<key>, <default>) seems a good, can you provide the sample code; all the data is provided, really tried...